# Python magic attributes display as bold

Tags: support, code-formatting

Whenever I write something like **init**, **class**, **str**, **repr** in a sentence it appears bold.

How can I stop this without having to put it in a separate code block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__init__`, `__class__`, `__str__`, `__repr__` can be done by using the "`" (backtick) character before and after the selected text. This marking allows for inline code. This markup can also be used within comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'quote' button instead of the 'code' button, then you won't get any of the color bolding stuff.

Comment: But it **is** code.